# Forticlient VPN SSL DNS works fine with a Mac, but not with Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, network-manager, dns, vpn

I got a connection with a VPN. I use Forticlient VPN SSL.

When I use my mac, I connect normally to the VPN and then go to somesiteinmyDNS/mythings and works perfectly fine.

However, when I connect with the same parameters using Ubuntu 16.04, the DNS won't work. The connection is fine but the DNS is not working.

I am using Forticlient SSLVPN 4.4.2333-1 64bit in Ubuntu.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with DNSmasq.

Add a DNS to my connection (for example 127.0.1.1) using Ubuntu's GUI.

Add the line localhost 127.0.1.1 to my hosts file.

Add listen-address 127.0.1.1 to dnsmasq.conf .

Restart DNSmasq.

There you go.